# General dispersion relation

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, dispersion

What "General dispersion relation", has to do with Dispersion relation , in general?
And what is the use of it in cosmology?

Comment: Mahla. I answered below the question, best I understood what you were looking for. So did Countto10. It's a good question if you write some more context on it. Like in what context did you find the dispersion or general dispersion relations that you have the question on, where did you read of them, and what did you see of them related to cosmology? With some context it bring up a topic in cosmology, and perhaps in other areas, of a lot of interest in this site. If not for this one for your next question it'd help. It does mean you might need to do some initial simple Google research

Comment: @BobBee I'm master student in particle physics but my teacher works on cosmology and more specific in gravity,as my proposal he suggested me to work on General dispersion relation and it's relation to Quantum loop gravity theory and Gravitational waves,but it is quiet vague for me to find the connection between these subjects.

Comment: It could be a good topic. I don't know enough loop gravity to say, but it would have to do with gravitational waves for sure. The perturbations to the mass density and metric have 3 different kinds of modes, scalar, vector and tensor. The tensor ones would produce gravitational waves. About a year ago a group said they had detected those on some patterns induced in the CMB. It was later shown that it was due to something else. If discovered it would be a confirmation of inflation. Maybe Google tensor perturbations of the CMB or related. Dodelson book has lots on it, but no loop gravity

Comment: Oh, one more. I ignored saying the there are GR alternatives, and quantum gravity theories, that have the speed of gravitational waves varying some with freq . That would be dispersion relations for gravitational perturbations. If so, gravitational waves would arrive separated in time, as function of frequency. We would be able to measure that, depending on the measurements made. So far there's been only two detections of grav waves, and as far as I remember, no indication of dispersion. Maybe this is what your prof meant, if maybe loop gravity predicts it and if measurable. Google that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dispersion relations are the equations relating frequency to wavelength or wavenumber, or either one to the speed of any waves. For light in vacuum $\omega$ (w 2pi*frequency) and k (2pi/wavelength) are proportional with c as the proportionality factor. If that's not true, as in a prism, where different wavelengths or freqs have different indices of refraction and the different colors separate.

It's used for any wave phenomena.

In cosmology it has been used for the density perturbations of matter, and including the spatial variations in mass density, I.e, it's about the formation of structure (such as galaxies, stars) due to gravitational attraction in the expanding universe. So the waves are then waves of the metric perturbation due to matter density perturbation, in an expanding universe. Since they arise from density perturbations they are sometimes called acoustic perturbations

An example is at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.5708v2.pdf where it is used to get the growth of perturbations due to inflation very early in the universe. This is called the trans-Planckian problem, because the start of inflation is at about Planckian times and sizes, in the early part of inflation. Different posited quantum gravity models lead to different dispersion relations during those times, with $\omega$ and k not proportional, i.e., the speed of the density perturbations varying with the size of the perturbations.

Another example of its use is at https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.06891.

Note that these  primordial perturbations later grew into the density inhomogeneities and anisotropy we see due to the formation of higher density regions like galaxies and stars, and cluster/superclusters. Those are also reflected, as the perturbations were read at about 380,000 years after the Big Bang, in the CMB.

For the CMB see http://www.weizmann.ac.il/particle/waxman/Cosmo/linearpert_CMB.pdf, where they treat the acoustic perturbations, i.e. The density fluctuations that gave rise to the anisotropy of the CMB, and now measured.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I am not putting this in the comments, as it does not answer your question directly,  is because by reading the abstract below, I hope that  you might get a better idea if it is related to what you are looking for.

This is definitely a subject I know next to nothing about, but the article/pdf seems to suggest the modification of particular dispersion relations to more general situation. An example that especially caught my eye was the paper below, in which standard, well known dispersion relations are "pushed" into currently uncharted territory, such as the Planck scale, and I this is what general dispersion relations means in this case.

My tablet won't copy the url, but searching for hep-th/0109128 PDF - arXiv.org  or the title below should find it. My apologies for that, and I hope you get a proper answer.

Abstract from [General Dispersion Relation](http://The%20stress-energy%20tensor%20for%20trans-Planckian%20cosmology)

The stress-energy tensor for trans-Planckian cosmology

Martin Lemoine, Musongela Lubo, Jerome Martin and Jean Philippe Uzan.

> This article presents the derivation of the stress-energy tensor of a free scalar field with a general non-linear dispersion relation in curved spacetime. This dispersion relation is used as a phenomelogical description of the short distance structure of spacetime following the conventional approach of trans-Planckian modes in black hole physics and in cosmology. This stress-energy tensor is then used to discuss both the equation of state of trans-Planckian modes in cosmology and the magnitude of their backreaction during ination. It is shown that gravitational waves of trans-Planckian momenta but subhorizon frequencies cannot account for the form of cosmic vacuum energy density observed at present,contrary to a recentclaim.The back reactioneects during ination are confirmed to be important and generic for those dispersion relations that are liable to induce changes in the power spectrum of metric uctuations. Finally, it is shown that in pure de Sitter ination there is no modication of the power spectrum except for a possible magnication of its overall amplitude independently of the dispersion relation.